# SIP - linksys and no voice

Tags: sip

I have a PC and a Linksys SPA3102.

I have connected them directly with an etthernet cable (pc address 192.168.0.10, linksys address 192.168.0.1). An analog phone device is connected to linksys (plugged into "Phone" socket).

I turned off PC's firewall.

In Linksys configuration I set:

- Preferred codec: g711a (PCMA)
- Register: no;
- Make call without reg: yes;
- ans call without reg: yes;

I use [pjsua](http://www.pjsip.org/pjsua.htm) to make a call call with arguments

```
pjsua --bound-addr 192.168.0.10 --no-vad --add-codec pcma sip:192.168.0.1
```

The analog phone rings but when I answer it no sound is available in any direction.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Damn it... nobody knows :((((

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. In case anybody encounters the same problem.

SPA3102 does allow calling from WAN only, so  I had to plug my PC to "internet" port instead "ethernet" port.